# Debugging push function from stack class I wrote in c++

Tags: c++, class, stack

*this program has been debugged, not edited here*

But whenever I try to push elements onto the stack, it crashes. What could I be doing wrong? The function prototype and other code seems to be fine.

The problem in Push() has been resolved, though I do not edit it over here (for those who like debugging) Have a look at the Display() function as well.

---

Here's the WHOLE program:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
using namespace std;


class Stack {
    static const int Default_size = 100;
private:
    int a[100];
    int ele;
    int max_size;
    int top;

public:

    Stack(int k){
        int top = -1;
        int max_size = k;
    }

~Stack(){ delete [] a; }

public:
void Push(const int ele1);
void Pop();
bool Is_Full();
bool Is_empty();
void Display();
};

void Stack:: Push ( const int ele1) {
    if(Is_Full())  
        cout<<"StackOverflow";
    else 
        a[++top] = ele1;
}






void Stack::Pop () {
    if(Is_empty()) 
    cout<<"Stack empty";
else    
    top--;
}

bool Stack:: Is_Full() {
    if(top == max_size)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}

bool Stack:: Is_empty() {
    if( top == -1)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}

void Stack :: Display () {
     for(int i = 0 ; i< top; i++)
     cout<<a[i];
}


int main() {
Stack s(5);
cout<<"1 to push, 2 to pop, 3 to display, 4 to exit";
int ch;
cin>>ch;
 while(ch != 4) {
    if( ch == 1) {
     cout<<"Enter element";
     int ele; cin>>ele;
     s.Push(ele);
    }
    else if( ch ==2) {
    s.Pop();
    }
    else if(ch == 3) {
    s.Display();
    }
    else 
    exit(0);
    cout<<"Enter ch";
    cin>>ch;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It crashed" isn't even close to descriptive enough.

Comment: @ikegami Still doesn't work. i'll post the whole of the program.

Comment: We don't want your whole program. Please post a **minimal**, runable demonstration of the program.

Comment: You also failed to provide the necessary input required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't call `delete [] a` in your destructor, because you didn't get `a` by using `new`.

You don't need an explicit destructor at all, in fact. Deleting it would make the code shorter and better, which is always a good feeling.

EDIT: Also your constructor is declaring two local variables rather than initialising your member variables. So `top` is not initialised when you call `Push`, which explains the crashes.

Much better would be

```
Stack(int k) : top(-1), max_size(k) { }
```

Comment: I noticed the `char` comparisons to non-printable characters in `main` instead.

Comment: @LogicStuff `ch` is an `int` (with a poorly-chosen name).

Comment: Of course I fell for it.

Comment: @LogicStuff Well at least you noticed it, I didn't until you mentioned it.

Comment: @AlanStokes Thank you, I removed the destructor, and fixed the constructor. Could you look at the display() function, it seems to be faulty too.

Comment: Looks OK to me. That sounds like a different question. (Alternatively, what does your debugger show you?)